# Joining on more than one Parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

When I join on one parameter I do get results:

```
join

SalesMapping m

on

(c.[MLIS Practice ID] = m.MLIS)
```

however when i join on 2 parameters, i get 0 results:

```
join

SalesMapping m

on

(c.[MLIS Practice ID] = m.MLIS and ltrim(rtrim(c.[QuikLab Practice Code]))=ltrim(rtrim(m.[Practice Code])))
```

i checked my source tables to check whether this join would yield any results, and it certainly would!

here is my entire query:

```
select 
[rep name]=m.[Sales Rep],
[css name]=m.[CSS Rep],
m.[Practice Name],
m.[Practice Code],

[MLIS Code]=m.[MLIS],
[Yesterday Volume]=(select 
                    COUNT([accession id]) 
                    from SpecimenCount 
                    where [MLIS Practice ID]=m.[MLIS]
                    and [Date Received]=CAST(getdate()-2 as DATE)),
[Today Volume] = (select 
                    COUNT([accession id]) 
                    from SpecimenCount 
                    where [MLIS Practice ID]=m.[MLIS]
                    and [Date Received]=CAST(getdate()-1 as DATE)),
[Rep Email]=m.[sales rep],
[CSS Email]=m.[css rep],
[Manager Email]=m.manager

from 

SpecimenCount c

join

SalesMapping m

on

(c.[MLIS Practice ID] = m.MLIS and c.[quiklab practice code]=m.[practice code])

join 

ManagerNames

on ManagerNames.Name = m.Manager
```

why is my query (joining on two conditions) returning 0 results?

here is my thought process for the following:

```
c.[MLIS Practice ID] = m.MLIS and c.[quiklab practice code]=m.[practice code]
```

we can definitely join the two datasets, here is why:

```
+----------+----------+---------------+---------------+-----------------------+-----------+------------------+------------------+--------------+-----------+-----------+---------------+
| rep name | css name | Practice Name | Practice Code | quiklab practice code | MLIS Code | MLIS Practice ID | Yesterday Volume | Today Volume | Rep Email | CSS Email | Manager Email |
+----------+----------+---------------+---------------+-----------------------+-----------+------------------+------------------+--------------+-----------+-----------+---------------+
| na       | na       | na            | SCPMA         | SCPMA                 |    100004 |           100004 |               10 |            3 | na        | na        | na            |
+----------+----------+---------------+---------------+-----------------------+-----------+------------------+------------------+--------------+-----------+-----------+---------------+
```

as you can see the codes `100004` and `SCPMA` are the same and SHOULD join together

Comment: `i checked my source tables to check whether this join would yield any results, and it certainly would!` Clearly it *wouldn't*, otherwise you'd be getting those results! What makes you think that it would? Can you explain your reasoning in more detail? Then we might be able to see where you are going wrong.

Comment: @MarkByers thank you. i provided more info

Comment: Where is the information for `ManagerNames.Name` and `m.Manager` that might be your issue as well if the other join works but the manager name does not.

Comment: I can only thing.. that since one of the joins is string type, it could be failed by even one space.. can you trim them or force them to be exactly a mach?

Comment: @gbianchi they are both varchar(50)

Comment: @jzworkman i had to take them out because it is private info

Comment: @I__ Understandable, just wanted to check that they are indeed the same as well.

Comment: that they have the same field def, doesn't accurate tell that they will have the same type of info.. for a join "dummy" is not the same as "DUMMY" and not even like "dummy "

Comment: varchar doesn't guarantee no whitespace at the ends.  If something is entered with whitespace it will be there.  Does "c.[quiklab practice code]=m.[practice code])" work on it's own?

Comment: @telos no, when i try to do join only on c[quiklab pra.... it doesnt join

Comment: @gbianchi i made sure the cases were exactly the same, got same result

Comment: please note that i just did this (c.[MLIS Practice ID] = m.MLIS and ltrim(rtrim(c.[QuikLab Practice Code]))=ltrim(rtrim(m.[Practice Code]))) and still same result

Comment: can you post data from two tables separately  without joined result set as shown in original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK is it possible you don't have spaces but have hidden, unprintable characters (Like TAB)? That woudl cause the join to fail.

Answer (score 2):

So you've verified that there are existing MLIS and practice codes that would join... but there's really a third condition as you are joining on the Manager also.  I don't see manager in your sample data, but I'd be willing to bet that there is no manager that matches a mlis/practice code pair.

Generally an easy way to identify a situation like this is to go through your joins one by one, and comment out or turn it into a left join.  Once the data comes back you know what's causing the issue.

Comment: very good thought! i left out that last join on manager and still getting 0 results

Answer (score 1):

Can you identify the presence of even one row that should be in your result set?  Can you verify that data IS in your tables?  The most common way I've had this trouble is by using the wrong name for a column.

oh, and don't do partial aliasing, it has caused me lots of trouble, it will cause you trouble eventually as well.  (Alias ManagerNames)

First, verify that there are matches between MangerName and SalesMapping on `MangerName.Name=SalesMapping.Manager`

```
select distinct Name from ManagerNames

select distinct Name from ManagerNames
except 
select distinct Manager from SalesMapping

--get less rows with the second query.
```

Second, verify that there are matches between SpecimenCount

```
select distinct [MLIS Practice ID],[quiklab practice code] from SpecimenCount

select distinct [MLIS Practice ID],[quiklab practice code] from SpecimenCount
except
select MLIS,[practice code] from SalesMapping.

--get less rows with the second query.
```

What you will probably find, is that the data doesn't match.  Then you will have to go back to the developers and get more info on how the tables were populated so you can match the columns.  Since no one bothered to make the column names identical, I'd guess the matching will NOT be straightforward.

Good Luck.

Comment: jerry thanks so much for your help. in the first set of your queries, the second one returned 0 rows, whereas in the second set of queries both returned equal amounts of rows